# jQuery + extending Object.prototype = "c.replace is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype, replace

I am using jQuery 1.5 in my open source project and following line is also present in my own Javascript code:

```
/**
 * Object.isEmpty()
 *
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function ()
{
    /**
     * @deprecated Since Javascript 1.8.5
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object
     */
    if ( this.__count__ !== undefined )
    {
        return this.__count__ === 0 ? true : false;
    }

    /* Less-aesthetic method, if above method fails */
    for ( var property in this )
    {
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty(property) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

which just extends Object.prototype adding isEmpty() method to it [that checks whether the object is empty or not). Because of this addition, I am getting "c.replace is not a function" error in my Firebug console; and my research on the web lead me to jQuery [bug tracker message](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/262), where I "learned" that extending Object.prototype not only breaks jQuery, but also is bad coding practice. My question is, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECMA-262 5th Edition (and JavaScript 1.8.5) has ways to do it through the `Object.defineProperty` and `Object.defineProperties` methods, by setting the `enumerable` field of the property to `false`. That is available in Chrome 5, Safari 5, Firefox 4 and Internet Explorer 9 or any recent server side implementation that uses V8 (like Node.js).

Comment: Thanks.. Although from technical standpoint its not wise to use this method (its only available on the newest gear), its good to know of its existence... [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, that because extending `Object.prototype` breaks the `for ... in` idiom.

In Javascript, if you have an object:

```
var obj = { "foo": 0, "bar": 42 };
```

You can iterate over its members by doing:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    // Do Something.
}
```

Extending `Object.prototype` will result in the extended members being present in all object instances, so the code above would iterate over more keys than `foo` and `bar`, with probably unexpected results.

You can find a fiddle demonstrating the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y67JR/).

Comment: I know that, but question still remains: 1) How to add (extend) additional methods (not properties) to Object? 2) If you can distinguish immediate children of your object from global ones, with help of hasOwnProperty(), why it is a bad coding?

Comment: @Shehi, well, to my knowledge the answers are: 1) Since methods and properties are both object members, the same principle applies, so, if possible, don't do that. 2) That would require not only your own code, but also all the other code that runs in the same page, to use `hasOwnProperty()`, so it would require all user agents to support it and cooperation from everybody at once. Also, `hasOwnProperty()` has a performance cost that many people would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

> **1)** How to add (extend) additional methods (not properties) to `Object`?

As long as **third party** code is running on your page you shouldn't.

> **2)** If you can distinguish immediate children of your object from global ones, with help of `hasOwnProperty()`, why it is a bad coding?

Because there's a likelihood that **other** programmers are lazy, and you **break** their code. It is a good practice not to modify **what you don't own**. `Object.prototype` is one of these things.

Use `MyLib.isEmpty(obj)`, or `isEmpty(obj)` inside your own scope so there's no chance to collide.

Comment: Actually it's the other programmer's bad code that is already broken if they for..in without a hasOwnProperty or prototype check. Just because the typical practices of a community doesn't result in an exception doesn't mean it's the fault of the person who extended object.prototype.  Those lazy programmers broke their own code to begin with - in the same way not including a default case in a switch statement is considered broken regardless of whether a case will ever exist that isn't explicitly coded for.